# Inherit a pure virtual function that throws

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, throw

as the title follows I would like to make an inherited class-function from a class-function that throws an exception. The function in the baseclass looks as follow:

```
template <typename T>
class IQueue {
public:
virtual T dequeue()throw(…) = 0;
}
```

Note that I'm not allowed to modify this since it's for a class. How am I suppose to declare the function in the diverted class? I have tried like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Queue : public IQueue < T >{
public:
virtual T dequeue()throw(…) {}
}
```

But I'm not allowed to run it, and it's giving me error that points to the declaration in the baseclass. So I'm thinking that I'm not overriding it as I should.

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
syntax error : indentifier '...'
unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation".
```

and the two at the top are in the IQueue.h and the last one in xlocale.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: "`throw(…)`" I hardly recommend that you use exception specifications in C++. Not only they don't do anything useful on some platforms, not only they are deprecated, but they were also voted for removal in C++17 except for the empty specification (`throw()`)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @KABoissonneault, and `noexcept` is better `throw()`.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen other people talked about that as well, but the thing is that I have to use the baseclass I'm given here. It's for a assignment and I'm not allowed to modify it

Comment: Yes, we want to see the error message.

Comment: @Allan Strokes, I'm getting some "unexpected token(s) preceding ';'" and "syntax error : indentifier '...'" and "unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation". I'm using Visual Studio 13 and there aren't any red marking under the code. It's just those errors

Comment: Might the problem be due to the use of the [Unicode Horizontal Ellipsis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) character?

Comment: @Kupiakos, It appears to work if I'm changing that symbol to '...' instead. I just copied the class from the assignment since they said that we weren't allowed to modify it

Comment: In g++, If I remove (...) then the code compiles fine. Can you try removing the (...) and see if it works in Visual studio? If it works, email the course TA. to correct it:).

Comment: There is a very real possibility that the people teaching you are - and this is the politest way I can put it - not paying enough attention to detail.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is due to using the [Unicode HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) character `…` instead of `...`. However, even `throw(...)` is not compiling on my system. The class is also missing a semicolon at the end of its declaration, although it's not clear if that was a just a mistake when uploading to Stack Overflow.

You mentioned that you copied the class from an assignment description. Whatever this was copied from does not format text correctly, and this should be fixed by the professor/whoever manages the assignments.

Also, in general, using exception specifications is considered a [bad idea](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) in C++, anyways.

Comment: Yeah this is it, I changed it so it's three dots '...' now instead and it's working fine. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Adam Glad to help. If an answer solved your problem, you can mark it as the solution by clicking the checkmark below the voting arrows on that question.